# jquery flash and dynamic variables

Tags: jquery

How can I include this varibale without it shooting me an error

The variable is vid on the vars line

```
$('.playVideo').live('click',function(z){
            z.preventDefault();//Disable Default Method
            var vid = $(this).attr('data');
```

....

```
$('#video').empty().flash({
    "src":"video/videoplayer-loop.swf",
    "width":322,
    "height":275,
    "vars":{"image":"img/video-posterframe-product.jpg","videoLink=player/video/"+vid+".flv","hideAudio1":"false","videoVolume":"50"},

});
```

I get thrown a

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 2):

The `vid` variable is out of scope, you need to either put these two bits of code in the same function:

```
$('.playVideo').live('click',function(z){
    z.preventDefault();//Disable Default Method
    var vid = $(this).attr('data');

    $('#video').empty().flash({
        "src":"video/videoplayer-loop.swf",
        "width":322,
        "height":275,
        "vars":{"image":"img/video-posterframe-product.jpg", "videoLink=player/video/" + vid + ".flv", "hideAudio1": "false", "videoVolume": "50"},
    });
});
```

Or put the code which sets up the flash into it's own function and call it from your click handler, passing the `vid` variable:

```
$('.playVideo').live('click',function(z){
    z.preventDefault();//Disable Default Method
    var vid = $(this).attr('data');
    setUpFlash(vid);
});

function setUpFlash(video) {
    $('#video').empty().flash({
        "src":"video/videoplayer-loop.swf",
        "width":322,
        "height":275,
        "vars":{"image":"img/video-posterframe-product.jpg", "videoLink=player/video/" + video + ".flv", "hideAudio1": "false", "videoVolume": "50"},
    });
});
```

You could also declare the `vid` variable globally, but this is not best practice.

Comment: why you say it's not best practice to declare 'vid' globally?

Comment: See the top answer in this question - it explains it better than I could: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063878/javascript-global-variables-best-practices

Comment: I am getting the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token + when trying the setup above

Comment: on line 119. Here is the script.  http://www.pavlishgroup.com/projects/tumbltrak/

Answer (score 0):

try to declare `var vid` outside any function

```
var vid;
$('.playVideo').live('click',function(z){
    z.preventDefault();//Disable Default Method
    vid = $(this).attr('data');
    ....
}
```