# Javascript global variable redefinition?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global-variables

I have a questions regarding variable scope in Javascript. I have a series of scripts on a webpages loading at different times. I need a global object called MyVar for example to be accessible to them all. I want to avoid redefining it but I guess it has to be defined at some point by the first script. My question is is using `var MyVar = MyVar || {}` a solution?

Thanks

```
 /**
 * Script 1
 */


var MyVar = MyVar || {};
MyVar.config = {
    x : 2,
    y : 3
};


/**
* Script 2
*/

//is this correct?
var MyVar = MyVar || {};
//to which MyVar am I assigning the apple property?
MyVar.apple = 'red';
```

**UPDATE**

Great answers so far guys thanks.

One last part though, what is the second var statement doing when I repeat `var MyVar = MyVar || {};` for the second time? Is it creating a new var in the global scope called `MyVar` that is assigned the value of the existing `MyVar` ?

Other posters are right to assume I have these scripts loading synchronously in `<script>` tags however due to division of labour I create the scripts then don't control when and how they are loaded so need a fool-proof method to create / utilize my `MyVar` object.

Thanks

Comment: Check out [this question about best practices when dealing with global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5063878/562906)

Comment: Yes, your code will work. Yes, you should avoid globals whenever possible.

Comment: Read `var MyVar = MyVar || {};` as `var MyVar = MyVar if it exists (and isn't equal to false or 0) , or a new object if it doesn't`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a series of scripts on a webpages loading at different times

Is any of them loaded asynchronously? If it's just a series of `<script>` tags, they will be loaded synchronously, in sequence.

> to which MyVar am I assigning the apple property?

If you declare `MyVar` on the global scope every time, there will be only one `MyVar`. The `apple` property will be created on the existing variable, if it exists, or in the empty object created with `var MyVar = MyVar || {};` if it doesn't.

Bottom line: after the first `var MyVar = MyVar || {};`, following declarations will be ignored, and new properties will be appended to the existing variable. Just be careful not to overwrite existing properties.

Comment: This is a good explanation. One last part though, what is the second var statement doing when I repeat `var MyVar = MyVar || {};` for the second time? Is it creating a new var in the global scope called `MyVar` that is assigned the value of the existing `MyVar` ?

Comment: It will do `MyVar = MyVar` (which is basically doing nothing at all).

Comment: @JackMahoney - To clarify, only the first `var` definition for a particular variable name actually defines that variable. Any subsequent `var` statement for the same variable name essentially does nothing; specifically, it does *not* create a new variable with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct and will probably work as expected, but bear in mind the scope in which `MyVar` is created. Assuming your files are as posted, they would create `MyVar` within the `window` scope (assuming a browser context). If one of them was wrapped in an anonymous function, as is common practice with the [Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript), `MyVar` would only be created within the scope of that function:

```
(function() {
    var MyVar = MyVar || {};
    // If MyVar doesn't already exist in the global context,
    // the current MyVar reference will only be scoped to this function.
})();
```

A better pattern to use is:

```
var MyVar = window.MyVar || (window.MyVar = {});
```

This will ensure it is always created, and referenced, from the global scope. You could even pass in the context in order to make future refactorings easier:

```
(function(context) {
    var MyVar = context.MyVar || (context.MyVar = {}));
})(window);
```

Comment: Thanks. So in `var MyVar = window.MyVar` is `MyVar` a reference to `window.MyVar` or is it an assignment of value?

Comment: If `window.MyVar` exists, your local `MyVar` variable will be a reference to it. If it doesn't exist, the second part `|| (window.MyVar = {})` will create a new object, assign it to `window.MyVar` and return the reference which will be assigned to the local `MyVar` variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to test:

```
var MyVar = MyVar || {};
MyVar.config = {
    x : 2,
    y : 3
};

console.log(MyVar);

var MyVar = MyVar || {};
MyVar.apple = 'red';

console.log(MyVar);
```

Comment: What if the order the scripts are referenced is changed? Your example is not good defensive programming.

Comment: I read it as two separate window-level scripts. I suppose they could  be reordered within the html, but I think that goes beyond Jack's question.

Comment: @ic3b3rg you're right they are two separate scripts and I don't know what order they will be in

Comment: In that case, @roryf's advice is better, although you might find my suggestion to test with console.log helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
window.myVar||(window.myVar={});
```

This way you are not re-declaring the variable if it already exists.