# JavaScript - function can't acces variables from another function scope

Tags: javascript, scope, modularity

I am trying to create a slider with javscript. I would like to have two functions - first of them, `parseDom()`, should be responsible for getting elements from DOM; the second one, `configureRange()`, should be responsible for setting range attributes, like `min` and `max` values. Both functions are called inside anonymous function, which is assigned to `window.onload` variable.

```
function parseDom() {
  var main = document.getElementById('main');
  main.classList.add('red');
  //   red class added - main selector is ok
  var rangeContainer = main.querySelector('.range-container');
  rangeContainer.classList.add('green');
  //   green class added - rangeContainer selector is ok
  var rangeInput = rangeContainer.querySelector('.range-input');
  rangeInput.classList.add('crosshair');
  //   crosshair class added - rangeInput selector is ok

}

function configureRange(){
  rangeInput.classList.add('pointer');
  rangeInput.setAttribute('min', '0');
}

window.onload = function(){
  parseDom();
  configureRange();
}
```

However, variables from `parseDom()` can't be accesed from `configureRange()`, because variables inside these functions are in different scopes. So my code inside `configureRange()` does not work. I could do all things in one function instead of two, but this would make code messy. How do I create a good modular solution?

Code is here:
https://codepen.io/t411tocreate/pen/oeKwbW?editors=1111

Comment: Pass parameters to the functions.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing is probably to pass `configureRange` the information it needs, by having `parseDom` call it:

```
function parseDom() {
  var main = document.getElementById('main');
  main.classList.add('red');
  //   red class added - main selector is ok
  var rangeContainer = main.querySelector('.range-container');
  rangeContainer.classList.add('green');
  //   green class added - rangeContainer selector is ok
  var rangeInput = rangeContainer.querySelector('.range-input');
  rangeInput.classList.add('crosshair');
  //   crosshair class added - rangeInput selector is ok
  configureRange(rangeInput);             // <==== Added call
}

function configureRange(rangeInput){      // <==== Note new parameter
  rangeInput.classList.add('pointer');
  rangeInput.setAttribute('min', '0');
}

window.onload = function(){
  parseDom();
  //                                         <==== Removed call
}
```

...or by having a controller function (`parseAndConfigure`, whatever) that looks up the input and passes it to both functions.

---

Side note: In terms of keeping functions small and ensuring the name is indicative of what it does (as seems to be your goal), `parseDom` doesn't parse anything, and it does more than just identify the relevant DOM elements (it also adds classes to them). Perhaps three functions: `getDom`, `addClasses`, and `configureRange` or similar. Then:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var dom = getDom();
    addClasses(dom);
    configureRange(dom);
}
```

...or something like that.

Comment: The ideal solution would be the second one as it clearly defines what is taking place in the code and removes any chance of clashes with variables.

Comment: @Script47: Yeah, my view as well. It really should have been up above that line, not below it, but I'll leave it as-is since I see there are now other answers (like [adeneo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46133778/157247)) where it's up-front where it belongs. ([A Macdonald's as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46133795/157247), although without the `getDom` function.)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the elements in an object, and then return that object, to be reused anywhere else

```
function parseDom() {
  var els = (function(d) {
    var main           = d.getElementById('main'),
        rangeContainer = main.querySelector('.range-container'),
        rangeInput     = rangeContainer.querySelector('.range-input');

    return {main, rangeContainer, rangeInput};
  })(document);

  els.main.classList.add('red');
  els.rangeContainer.classList.add('green');
  els.rangeInput.classList.add('crosshair');

  return els;
}

function configureRange(els) {
  els.rangeInput.classList.add('pointer');
  els.rangeInput.setAttribute('min', '0');

  return els;
}

window.onload = function() {
  var elems = parseDom();
  configureRange(elems);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simplest approach would be to abstract the selectors away from the parseDom function, maybe call that updateDom instead and parse the selectors in the top level function e.g.

```
function updateDom(main, rangeContainer, rangeInput) {
  main.classList.add('red');
  //   red class added - main selector is ok

  rangeContainer.classList.add('green');
  //   green class added - rangeContainer selector is ok

  rangeInput.classList.add('crosshair');
  //   crosshair class added - rangeInput selector is ok

}

function configureRange(rangeInput){
  rangeInput.classList.add('pointer');
  rangeInput.setAttribute('min', '0');
}

window.onload = function(){
  var main = document.getElementById('main'),
    rangeContainer = main.querySelector('.range-container'),
    rangeInput = rangeContainer.querySelector('.range-input');

  updateDom(main, rangeContainer, rangeInput);
  configureRange(rangeInput);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your variables inside the `.onload`, then pass them as arguments to as many functions as you like:

```
function parseDom(main, rangeContainer, rangeInput) { // <= arguments
  main.classList.add('red');
  rangeContainer.classList.add('green');
  rangeInput.classList.add('crosshair');
}

function configureRange(rangeInput){ // <= argument
  rangeInput.classList.add('pointer');
  rangeInput.setAttribute('min', '0');
}

window.onload = function(){
  var main = document.getElementById('main'),
    rangeContainer = main.querySelector('.range-container'),
    rangeInput = rangeContainer.querySelector('.range-input'),
    // other elements
  parseDom(main, rangeContainer, rangeInput); // <= pass as arguments
  configureRange(rangeInput); // <= pass as argument
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea at all. This is just ['code smell'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063878/how-to-cleanly-deal-with-global-variables). The better option would be to pass parameters.

Comment: @Script47 It's good for modularity, when you have tens of functions that manipulate the same elements.

Comment: Look at @T.J.Crowder second solution, that would deal with the scenario that you have posed.

Comment: @Script47 It's brilliant, probably my answer could've been better if I moved the variables inside the `.onload`, well, too late.

Comment: It's never too late to improve an answer!

Comment: @Script47 Did so.