# How to get the click event values outside the function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the onclick event (this value change when click on div) in jQuery?

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
  var v = $(this).val();
});

$(function(){
  alert(v);
});
```

Comment: You are going to need to explain your issue a little better ? what do you want to happen when ?

Comment: Maybe give some example code that isn't working, and an explanation of what you want to happen?

Comment: `funtion`? I believe you mean `function`

Comment: ya that by  spell mistake thats function

Comment: If you simply want access to the event, you can do this: $("ul li").click(function(event){
  var clickEvent = event;
});

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {

    var v;

    $('ul li').click(function() {
        v = $(this).val(); // .text() - consider
        testFunction();
    });

    function testFunction() {
        alert(v);
    }

});
```

Your issue was variable scope, you were defining a variable only available to the click function. If you define it outside of the function it will be available to other *in scope* functions.

Here's a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/vs87B/

You might want to consider using `.text()` instead of `.val()`

Comment: hey i want to use click value in another funtion

Comment: You can use `v` in any other function inside the `$(function() {});` call with this code.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand that you want to change the text of a div

your div is as follow

```
 <div>123</div>
```

you can do it as

```
<script>

$("div").click(function () {
 $(this).replaceWith( "new text " );
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**
you can use global variable as follow

```
 $.mynamespace = {};
$("ul li").click(function(){
       $.mynamespace.myVar  = $(this).val();
});

$(function(){
  alert( $.mynamespace.myVar );
});
```

refer [How to store a global value (not necessarily a global variable) in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866866/jquery-global-variable-best-practice-options)

Comment: i mean to ask is if i decalere the value to golbal , im not getting the change value when in funtion onlick

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean getting the innerHTML of the div when clicked, here is a code that could help

```
$("div").click(function(){console.log($(this).html())})
```

Comment: not exaclty i mean to ask is on click funtion the values change na i have to use in outside that funtion which is dnamic

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean ... please try to rephrase your question ;)