# Access a global var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation like this one:

```
talenti = $(".talenti");
filtra = $(".filtra");
wrapNavHeight =  $("#wrapNav").outerHeight(true);
filtra.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".nasco").hide();
    $("#sliding-navigation").delay(delay).show();
    delay += 500;
    talenti.removeClass('opened');
    filtra.addClass('opened');
    filtra.attr('id',"focF");
    talenti.attr('id',"");
    if (filtra.hasClass("opened")) {
        $("#wrapNav").slideToggle("100", "linear", function(){
            alert(wrapNavHeight);
            $("#container").animate({"height": "+=wrapNavHeight"}, 100,function(){
                $(".box").animate({"top": "+=wrapNavHeight"});
            });
        });
    } 
});
```

I am trying to get wrapNavHeight but alert(wrapNavHeight); outputs null; can't then assign that value to the next animate lines

Anyone?

Comment: check `$("#wrapNav").outerHeight(true);`, what does it return? is `wrapNav` id right?

Comment: #wrapNav is indeed an id. At the very start if I check its value with an alert it will return null as it is display: none; but I am then using slideToggle and it does expand it and reveal it so its height then be defined when I ask its value in the alert as per the above code but for some reasons it still return null

Comment: I second what David C. suggested - most probably `outerHeight()` returns `null` - which could mean that you call it on an empty set of elements - i.e. `#wrapNav` points to noting (http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/). But it may also depend on the jQuery version you are using - there were some bugs related to it, like [this one](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7693)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isn't it just that you are assigning the variable the value of `outerHeight` at the time it's not visible? I think you need to re-evaluate `outerHeight` after the toggle transition.  Replace

```
alert(wrapNavHeight);
```

with

```
alert($("#wrapNav").outerHeight(true));
```

see if that's any better?

Comment: You are perfectly right and not just makes sense but it does return the correct value. Any idea why the global var i assign at the top, wrapNavHeight, it is no read by the animate? At the animate point $("#wrapNav").outerHeight(true) (which is defined as wrapNavHeight at the top) is a value as alert says when using your suggeston

Comment: not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, but if you're trying to add wrapNavHeight to #container height, then something like this might do it:

Comment: var newHeight = $("#container").height() + $("#wrapNav").outerHeight(true);

Comment: sorry, prematurely hit return :)

Comment: right ok, yes it does what I'm looking for, newHeight is now the new and correct #container height, however can you see I have a second animate? The top: "value" should be the same as new added container height (basically the current $("#wrapNav").outerHeight(true); )

Comment: $("#container").animate({height: newHeight}, 100,function(){
                $(".box").animate({top: newHeight});
            });

Comment: mm nope, that would set the top distance as the height of #container + #wrapNav outerHeight, we only want to add the current #wrapNav outerHeight

Comment: added this as another variable just below the previous defined one (newHeight): var newDistance = newHeight - $("#container").height();
then to my second animate I did: $(".box").animate({top: newDistance}); it works great, just thinking if there is a shorter way rather than defining a new var to achieve this, otherwise it's fine, it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: One thing i would do is assign a variable to each jQuery element your are using so you don't have to traverse the DOM each time you are recalculating the heights, so create variables for $('#container'), $('#wrapNav'), etc

Answer (score 0):

Nobody else actually explained why this happens. Here's why:

It depends on:

- which object is used as "this" for invocation of the function containing all the code above
- which object is used as "this" for invocation of the function defined starting on line 4 of your code

In JavaScript, "global" references actually apply to the current `this` object (or to the "true" global object (`window` in web browsers) if not within a function)

Thus, if the `this` objects for the 2 functions I pointed out above are different, then you'll get the situation you observed.

In the browser, the default `this` object is usually `window`, but this can be changed when the function is run, such as by passing a different parameter to `apply` or by calling the function as a method.

Been a year since I used jQuery seriously, but if I recall right, jQuery event handlers usually rebind `this` to something useful related to the event (using apply-- you can do this too).

So, assuming the outer function's `this` hasn't been bound to anything special other than `window`, simply replace `wrapNavHeight` with `window.wrapNavHeight` in the inner function to achieve your desired effect.

(In practice I wouldn't actually do this, though, as a matter of style. Just declare `wrapNavHeight` as a `var` within the outer function instead, and then you'll get lexical scoping.)

Answer (score -1):

Try searching.

[jQuery global variable best practice & options?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2895772/171703)