# jQuery access to this event in new object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get access to the data-global-id value in the following markup and I am not sure how to do this due to scoping.

For example:

```
<div data-global-id="168" class="remove-as-favorite">remove as favorite</div>

$('.remove-as-favorite').on('click',function(){
  var global_id=$(this).data('global-id');
  // this works
  alert('here i am in something: ' + global_id);
  // this doesn't work
  event_handler.remove_as_favorite(); 
});


// want to access the data-global-id value in here; how to get access to this?
event_handler={
remove_as_favorite: function(){
    // how to get access to this here; assuming this refers to event_handler 
    var global_id=$(this).data('global-id');
    alert("here i am global_id:" + global_id);
  }
}
```

thx

** edit 1 ** 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this bruv: **working demo with global_id** http://jsfiddle.net/HK55Q/8/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/HK55Q/11/

In the code merely changing the declaration of global id outside the local function like this `var global_id = "";`

further the code should explain better,

**Good read:)** [How to store a global value (not necessarily a global variable) in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866866/jquery-global-variable-best-practice-options)

hope it helps, lemme know if I missed anything

**code**

```
var global_id = ""; //<=== See here the global_id variable is outside your click and now you can bind it and can use it again.

$('.remove-as-favorite').on('click',function(){
  global_id=$(this).data('global-id'); //<== Do not redeclare it using var global_id
  // this works
  alert('here i am in something: ' + global_id);
  // this doesn't work
  event_handler.remove_as_favorite(); 
});


// want to access the data-global-id value in here; how to get access to this?
event_handler={
remove_as_favorite: function(){
    // how to get access to this here; assuming this refers to event_handler 
    var global_id=$(this).data('global-id');
    alert("here i am global_id:" + global_id);
  }
}
```

Comment: working through this - not working right nwo but sure that's prob something wrong I'm doing

Comment: @timpone Glad I can help `:)` feel free to flick me demo I can help you out further if need be,

Comment: created this jsfiddle - doesn't seem to be working var http://jsfiddle.net/HK55Q/3/

Comment: Hiya @timpone cool so the global variable is working fine, but the `data('global_id')` element is nothing i.e. undefined see here and see alerts `:)` **working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/HK55Q/8/ **also PLease note** you defined `var global_id` twice see my code above :) the alert comment will guide you through.

Comment: so ideally I'd like to really only be accessing the global_id once - like in the even_handler object. There's a huge mess of getting these values in these event handlers and want to try to separate the on event calls from the getting of those values. Maybe just not doable

Comment: @timpone hmmm, `:)` not sure what do you mean, but flick me jsfiddle I will help you out further, also above demo should help you to understand how you can use global variable. lemme knw how it goes

Comment: so ideally, I'd like to get somethign like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sFEXy/1/ so that we could just separte the listing of the actual on evetns from the logic

Comment: @timpone okies seems yo don't need global variable and you just need 2 separate variables then?

Comment: well, I think i just need to figure out how to get access to this within the second function. I think the creation of the event_handler object is the source of the problem. I am pretty sure we ahve soem working code that is very similar to this. ugh ...

Comment: @timpone hmmm have you seen this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HK55Q/8/ see the alert: `alert("Before change global_id: == >" + global_id);` gets the correct value in error handler function? `:P`

Comment: so the one I would want would be #3 but that is undefined for me. Will add screenshot as edit

Comment: lol @timpone read my comments carefully in here: http://jsfiddle.net/HK55Q/9/ you are using your `var` incorrectly in #3 i.e. defining `var global_id` "twice"!

Comment: so i updated fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/HK55Q/10/ This is kinda what I want. Maybe I'm not getting what you're saying. thx for your patience.

Comment: @timpone **FIXED :)** see here: http://jsfiddle.net/HK55Q/11/ updating the post, this will help you out rest code will make it clear for you,

Answer (score 0):

You could do one of a couple things.  The simplest I can see is to pass global_id as an argument into the remove_as_favorite function, so that it would look like this:

```
$('.remove-as-favorite').on('click',function(){
  var global_id=$(this).data('global-id');
  event_handler.remove_as_favorite(global_id); 
});

// want to access the data-global-id value in here; how to get access to this?
event_handler={
remove_as_favorite: function(global_id){
    alert("here i am global_id:" + global_id);
```

}
}

The other way is to use either the "call" or "apply" functions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call

```
$('.remove-as-favorite').on('click',function(){
  var global_id=$(this).data('global-id');
  event_handler.remove_as_favorite.call(this); 
});
```

Comment: any idea how cross-browser call is?

Comment: Very cross browser... the .call method was added in JavaScript 1.3, it was introduced in Netscape Navigator 4 and IE 4.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler example would be to use call as follows:
​

```
$(function(){
    $('.remove-as-favorite').on('click',function(){
        var global_id=$(this).data('global-id');
        alert('here i am in something: ' + global_id);
        event_handler.remove_as_favorite.call({global_id:global_id}); 
    });


    event_handler = {
        remove_as_favorite: function() {
            alert("here i am global_id:" + this.global_id);
        }
    }
});​
```

And call is a javascript function, and is compatible with all the browsers, which support javascript ofcourse ;)

Check the fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/nTq97/

Comment: we have a set of functions following this pattern. The issue is we want to have a set of event-captures in a single file (like a routes.rb in a rails app) where we can just specify these captures but not have the actual getting of the variables here. In my opinion, it would just be a lot cleaner. Agreed that this would work. Would probably need to put into a args hash for more than one variable. REALLY REALLY want to figure out a clean way to do this.