# Assign global variable within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to assign global variable value within one function and use that variable in another function, but for some reason the variable comes out to be blank in the second function.

**My thoughts**

Either function 2 is executed first before function 1 (If this is the case, how do I command jQuery to start to execute a particular statement/function?)

Or

`myvar` global variable in function 1 is not set (if this is the case, what is the alternative to achieve this?)

```
var my_var;
//function 1
$(".div1").onhover(function(){
my_var="hello"
});
  
//function 2
$(".div1").onhover(function(){
 //i want to make use of my_var here, but it is blank
});
 
 //I want to use my_var it somewhere here too, but it doesnt work
```

Comment: Global variable in JQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352020/jquery-the-best-way-to-set-a-global-variable

Comment: The problem is that `function 2` gets called first; but it's not clear what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct function is `.hover` ([more here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)); `.onhover` is not correct. The code below works the way you requested ([live example](http://jsfiddle.net/EKdtj/2/)).

HTML

```
<div id="TestID" class="div1">This is a test.</div>​
```

JavaScript

```
var my_var;
//function 1
$(".div1").hover(function(){
    my_var=$(this).attr('id'); 
});

//function 2
$(".div1").hover(function(){
    alert(my_var);
});​
```

Here are some additional helpful links on Global variables in JavaScript:

- [How to declare a global variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352020/jquery-the-best-way-to-set-a-global-variable)
- [How to store a global value (not necessarily a global variable) in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866866/jquery-global-variable-best-practice-options)
- [Global variables in Javascript](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/02/global-variables-in-javascript/)

Comment: Thank you, when you use alert it works but when you use it within a statement it doesnt, onhover was a typo sorry.

Comment: Here's an example using the variable in a statement: http://jsfiddle.net/EKdtj/2/. It still works.

Comment: sorry i meant it doesnt work outside the function, how do i make it work?

Comment: If the mouse hasn't hovered over a `div` thus firing the functions, then `my_var` won't be defined. You should be able to reference it anywhere without a problem. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/EKdtj/4/

Comment: You'll have to post more code for with more context or modify one of the jsfiddles above replicating your issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20445/discussion-between-jsuar-and-katie)